# script with grep inside not work in crontab

Tags: grep, cron

I have a script that works launched manually, but when I put it in crontab the last grep command not works, could someone help me ?

the last  lines of script are :

```
# Generate YSFHosts.txt file
curl https://register.ysfreflector.de/export_csv.php > ${YSFHOSTS}

# Create a dedicated filtered file
grep ";IT" ./YSFHosts_dump.txt > YSFHost_ITALIA.txt

# Restart process
systemctl restart ysfgateway.service 

exit 0
```

this is the line put in crontab :

`0  0  *  *  *  /home/pi/YSF_INI_FILES/YSFHostsupdate.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1`

thank you in advance

Comment: A very significant number of issues with `cron` jobs result from one of two issues and both are present in your script. 1) You should always double quote variables when you use them, i.e. `"${YSFHOSTS}"` and 2) you need to set your PATH correctly at the top of a `cron` script because it doesn't have the PATH set like you do in an interactive shell - so find where `systemctl` and `grep` and `curl` are located and add the containing directories to your PATH at the top.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try,  I was wondering why it works not in crontab.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry but I'm new in programming, could you please give me an example how to set the PATH in script, I see the grep is in /bin, I tried to put /bin/grep in script and it not works :(   thank you

Comment: Add a line similar to this near the top `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/where/systemctl/is`

Comment: I did this, but not work :( the file is not updated after script run in crontab, is it possible that the crontab row is not correct ? thank you

Comment: Did you make the script executable with `chmod +x /home/pi/YSF_INI_FILES/YSFHostsupdate.sh`

Comment: SOLVED, I put the absolute path in the script for output and temp files and now it works !!! thank you for suggestions